# Sorting statement

Tags: database, db2

I want to sort my employee's age between 18-25 or whatsoever, but I don't know how to declare that query.

This is the query.

```
db2 => SELECT lastname, firstnme,  AVG(YEAR(CURRENT DATE - BIRTHDATE)) "Age upon hiring" FROM employee GROUP BY lastname, firstnme ORDER BY 1,3
```

This is the result of the query

```
 LASTNAME        FIRSTNME     Age upon hiring
--------------- ------------ ---------------
ADAMSON         BRUCE                     39
ALONZO          ROY                       60
BROWN           DAVID                     45
GEYER           JOHN                      60
GOUNOT          JASON                     60
HAAS            CHRISTINE                 53
HEMMINGER       DIAN                      43
HENDERSON       EILEEN                    45
JEFFERSON       JAMES                     36
JOHN            REBA                      38
JOHNSON         SYBIL                     39
JONES           WILLIAM                   13
KWAN            SALLY                     45
LEE             WING                      45
LUCCHESSI       VINCENZO                  56
LUTZ            JENNIFER                  38
MARINO          SALVATORE                 14
MEHTA           RAMLAL                    54
MONTEVERDE      ROBERT                    32
NATZ            KIM                       40
NICHOLLS        HEATHER                   40
O'CONNELL       SEAN                      43
ORLANDO         GREG                      43
PARKER          JOHN                      31
PEREZ           MARIA                     13
PIANKA          ELIZABETH                 36
PULASKI         EVA                       13
QUINTANA        DELORES                   60
SCHNEIDER       ETHEL                     40
SCHWARTZ        EILEEN                    50
SCOUTTEN        MARILYN                   37
SETRIGHT        MAUDE                     55
SMITH           PHILIP                    39
SMITH           DANIEL                    46
SPENSER         THEODORE                  35
SPRINGER        MICHELLE                  55
STERN           IRVING                    41
THOMPSON        MICHAEL                   38
WALKER          JAMES                     34
WONG            HELENA                    45
YAMAMOTO        KIYOSHI                   35
YOSHIMURA       MASATOSHI                 35

 42 record(s) selected.
```

So my question is how could I sort the column 3(AGE_UPON_HIRING) between 30 and 45?

BTW, I'm using db2 express C and using sample db.
PS: This is my 2nd time posting(asking) here :)
PSS: I Fixed my format :)

Comment: so your table contains more than 1 record for same employee? why exactly you are using group by? and for which column you want to sort by?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and result? It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, and I'm using the GROUP BY for this query "AVG(YEAR(CURRENT DATE - BIRTHDATE)) "AGE_UPON_HIRING"". And I want to sort the 3rd column by determining their age between 18 and 25 or so on.

Comment: But why? your employee table should contain 1 record for 1 employee. Why are you using group by?

Comment: I just fixed now my format, so can you briefly explain what you mean? And also if I don't add GROUP BY in my query, the query errors.

Comment: @Solarflare I just fixed now my format.

Comment: Your query errors when you remove group by because you have aggregate function. What im trying to figure out is, why are you getting avarage of YEAR(CURRENT DATE - BIRTHDATE)?

Comment: Ohhhhh, you're right, I didn't think about that thing. Sorry I just find it out on google. Can you please briefly explain to me what function I need to use to determine the age of my employees? Thanks in advance @hchaznedaroglu

Comment: ok then i will post an answer for you in a minute

Comment: Sorry, I meant the expected result. What are you trying to get? To order by the age, you can use `order by 3` (and as mentioned by others, you don't need a `group by`).

Comment: @Solarflare, I want to get the age of the employees between 30-45 (column 3). How is that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT lastname, firstnme, YEAR(CURRENT DATE - BIRTHDATE) "Age upon hiring"
FROM employee ORDER BY 3, 1
```

This query should order your result by employees age and if two employee have same age they will be sorted depending on their lastname. I didn't change much, just that your group by logic was not correct and columns in order by should be in reverse order. If this wont help you get the result you want, please share an expected output so that I can help further. Cheers!

Comment: THANKS ALOOTT!! YOU REALLY HELP ME A BUNCHH!!!! MY GUESS TO SORT THE AGE GOT WORKED!!!! REALLY DUDE!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! HOPE YOU HAVE A NICE DAY :)